# R data.table Size and Memory Limits

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 15.4GB R data.table object with 29 Million records and 135 variables. My system & R info are as follows:

```
Windows 7 x64 on a x86_64 machine with 16GB RAM."R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)" on "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

I get the following memory allocation error (see image)

[image]

I set my memory limits as follows:

```
#memory.limit(size=7000000)
#Change memory.limit to 40GB when using ff library
memory.limit(size=40000)
```

My questions are the following:

1. Should I change the memory limit to 7 TB
2. Break the file into chunks and do the process?
3. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The general rule is that you will need 3 times the physical memory of your largest object. I doubt that you will get satisfactory performance by allocating larger virtual memory. You might consider one of the EC2 strategies if your budget does not support tripling your RAM.

Comment: There is nice [Matt's tutorial](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Amazon-EC2-for-beginners) for setting up EC2 *spot instances* - those are much cheaper than *on-demand* instances. You can get multiple hours of powerful machine under a dollar.

Comment: Increasing the memory limit beyond the RAM size will cause swapping to disk and tear down the performance significantly (as already explained above by BondedDust).

Without knowing your source code it is hard to identify the code chunks that cause a waste of RAM so show us your code and describe the size of input data here if you want more help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to profile your code to identify which statements cause the "waste of RAM":

```
# install.packages("pryr")
library(pryr) # for memory debugging

memory.size(max = TRUE) # print max memory used so far (works only with MS Windows!)
mem_used()
gc(verbose=TRUE) # show internal memory stuff (see help for more)

# start profiling your code
Rprof( pfile <- "rprof.log", memory.profiling=TRUE) # uncomment to profile the memory consumption

# !!! Your code goes here

# Print memory statistics within your code whereever you think it is sensible
memory.size(max = TRUE)
mem_used()
gc(verbose=TRUE)

# stop profiling your code
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof(pfile,memory="both") # show the memory consumption profile
```

Then evaluate the memory consumption profile...

Since your code stops with an "out of memory" exception you should reduce the input data to an amount the makes your code workable and use this input for memory profiling...

Comment: This is very instructive & helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [ff](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/ff/) package. It works well with on disk data.