# How to run R models on large data sets?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a large data set(~10 GB) and I want to run a support vector machine or a linear model. Typically when I run these functions, I get an error message: 'Error: Cannot allocate vector of size 308.4 MB'. What is the best way to deal with this? Would creating random subsets and running the models on the individual subsets be a better approach?

Comment: I would recommend checking out the [`data.table` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) on SO. The package was designed for using large datasets with R. Also, check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223804/r-data-table-size-and-memory-limits). They appear to be dealing with similar issues as you.

Comment: "Would creating random subsets and running the models on the individual subsets be a better approach?" It largely depends on your goals, but yes, this is usually a reasonable approach.

Comment: since when does data table have SVM methods @RichardErickson